# How to type None if it expects a function type as type argument?

Tags: generics, rust, types, option-type

Suppose I have a function that takes a callback

```rs
fn foo<T>(callback: impl FnOnce(T) -> T, value: T) -> T {
    callback(value)
}
```

Suppose I now want to make this callback optional. The, in my view, most obvious way of doing that is to use `Option`:

```rs
fn foo<T>(callback: Option<impl FnOnce(T) -> T>, value: T) -> T {
    if let Some(callback) = callback {
        callback(value)
    } else {
        value
    }
}
```

However, when doing this, I run into a problem at the use site.
For instance, the following code does not compile:

```rs
fn bar() -> u8 {
    let value: u8 = b'.';
    let value = foo(None, value);
    value
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> XX:XX:XX
   |
XX |     let value = foo(None, value);
   |                     ^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the enum `Option`
   |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
XX |     let value = foo(None::<T>, value);
   |                         +++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
```

However, it seems impossible to provide a type for this, as `impl …` syntax does not work as a type argument here, and you’d need a concrete type from a closure anyways.

Is it possible to annotate the type for a missing closure like this?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide it a type that implements `FnOnce(u8) -> u8` since that is what `foo` requires, the simplest one I can think of is a function pointer:

```rust
fn bar() -> u8 {
    let value: u8 = b'.';
    let value = foo(None::<fn(_) -> _>, value);
    value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways. You'll need to pick a type that implements `FnOnce(T) -> T`. For the examples, I'll use `fn(T) -> T`, but it doesn't make much difference:

- use a turbofish:

```rust
foo(None::<fn(u8) -> u8>, 123);
```

- use a let binding with a type ascription

```rust
let option_fn: Option<fn(u8) -> u8> = None;
foo(option_fn, 123);
```

- make the generics named, and use the turbofish on `foo`:

```rust
fn foo<T, F: FnOnce(T) -> T>(f: F, t: T) -> T {
  ...
}

foo::<u8, fn(u8) -> u8>(None, 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the existing answers, supplying an identity function (one that returns its argument) would be the more appropriate functional style here, and has the advantage that it makes the whole problem go away.  It is also likely to perform better as there's no branch that can be incorrectly predicted.

```
fn identity<T>(v: T) -> T { v }

fn foo<T>(callback: impl FnOnce(T) -> T, value: T) -> T {
    callback(value)
}

fn bar() -> u8 {
    let value: u8 = b'.';
    let value = foo(identity, value);
    value
}
```

In other words, using `Option` can actually be *wasteful* when "no function" will cause the same observable behavior as "the identity function."

(Of course, `|v| v` is shorter than `identity`, so which you use is a matter of taste.)

This doesn't solve the general problem of how you specify `None` in the context of an optional function when the identity function shouldn't cause the same behavior as no function at all.  The other answers address how to handle that situation.  This answer is intended to provide a better solution when both cases *do* have the same behavior.

Comment: I guess this is an example of the X/Y problem—I’m actually writing a function where the relevant function would be called on an array of values, and skipping the iteration might be worthwhile. But thanks

Comment: `identity` is already defined in std: `std::convert::identity`.

Comment: @schuelermine Right -- my answer is also for people coming here from Google. :)